# Show GIF animation while time.sleep() in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to display a GIF-File in a webpage while in the background (Flask-Application) is a time.sleep() function. This is my code:
app.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def test():
    #Do something    
    time.sleep(2)    
    #Do something different
    
    return render_template("template.html")

app.run()
```

template.html:

```
<title>Test</title>
<p>Finally loaded</p>
```

My goal is that while the 2 seconds waiting a GIF-File should be shown. I tried this:

```
<div id="preloader"></div>
<style>
  #preloader{
    background: white url(/static/animation.gif) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 15%;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: wait;
  }
</style>
<script>
  var loader = document.getElementById("preloader");
  window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    loader.style.display = "none"
  })
  window.onload = preloader;
</script> 
<p>Done</p>
```

..., but the gif file is only displayed (for a short time) after the countdown. Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using only one endpoint because the `time.sleep(2)` blocks the response, so you only see the loading indicator after the sleep phase is finished. You need a separate endpoint for the task.

With some javascript we can call the task endpoint after the base page is loaded and during the request we can show the loading indicator. I'm using [HTMX](https://htmx.org/) library here for the demonstration.

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    # Base page that calls the task endpoint.
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/task")
def task():
    time.sleep(2)
    return '<span>Done</span>'
```

`index.html` base template:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.1"></script>
<div hx-get="/task" hx-trigger="load">
    <img class="htmx-indicator" src="/static/animation.gif" />
</div>
```

The two `hx-` attributes tells HTMX to load the `/task` endpoint on page load event and replace the `innerHTML` of the `div` element with the response. During the request, the indicator image will be visible, then it will be replaced with the response from `/task`.